# Поиск минимального расстояния между одинаковыми элементами

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, хеширование

Напишите псевдокод алгоритма, который находит в массиве два **одинаковых** элемента, расстояние между которыми в массиве минимально. То есть нужно найти индексы i*, j* такие, что:

> i*, j* = argmin{j - i | a_i = a_j, i < j}

Покажите, какую вычислительную сложность имеет ваш алгоритм и почему. Считайте, что размер массива не более 10^7, а элементы массива - целые числа от -10^18 до 10^18.

Первое решение, что пришло в голову это перебрать каждый элемент за O(n^2) и запомнить индексы одинаковых элементов и их разницу и так искать минимальное расстояние. Второе решение, это отсортировать a_i по возрастанию и дальше сравнивать по 2 числа
Например:

```
list index: [00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]  
list value: [ 2,  7,  1,  2,  4,  2,  9, 10,  7,  2,  4,  4, 10,  1,  8,  2,  5,  9,  6]
```

Сортируем и получаем такое

```
list index: [02, 13, 00, 03, 05, 09, 15, 04, 10, 11, 16, 18, 01, 08, 14, 06, 17, 07, 12]  
list value: [ 1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  4,  4,  4,  5,  6,  7,  7,  8,  9,  9, 10, 10]
```

Сравниваем по 2 элемента и запоминаем разницу индексов, потом находим минимальное значение
Сложность O(n log n). Как решить эту задачу за O(n)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда есть задача добиться времени выполнения O(N), надо подумать что можно сделать за O(1) и O(logN). Пробегаемся в голове по структурам данных. Т.к. у нас есть одинаковые элементы скорее всего что-то будет связано с множествами или `hashmap`, нам нужно работать не только с элементами, но и индексами, поэтому скорее всего нам подойдёт именно `hashmap` т.к. с её помощью мы сможем хранить элементы и индексы, время выполнения операций вставка и поиск выполняется за O(1).

Можно сделать так:

- Проитерироваться по всем элементам и положить их в `hashmap` (ключом является число, а значением будет индекс текущего элемента).
- Создадим переменную, которая будет хранить минимальную разницу `minDistance` и зададим ей `значение = размер исходного массива + 1`.
- При вставке в `hashmap`:

  - Если элемента (числа) нет среди ключей `hashmap`, то вставляем его и текущий индекс элемента
  - Если элемент присутствует в hashmap:

    - Вытаскиваем предыдущий индекс такого элемента
    - Находим разницу индексов (текущий индекс - значение по ключу в `hashmap`),
    - Сравниваем эту разницу с `minDistance`, если `minDistance` больше текущей разницы, то обновляем `minDistance`
    - Перезаписываем значение индекса для текущего элемента в `hashmap` текущим индексом (т.к. далее минимальная дистанция для двух одинаковых элементов будет только для тех элементов, которые были после текущего совпадения)